# operator T(){} - not working

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a code

```
class smallDOUBLE;

class smallINT
{
private:
    int val;   
public:
   smallINT():val(0){}
   smallINT(int i):val(i){}
   operator smallDOUBLE() {return val;}
};

class smallDOUBLE
{
private:
    double val;
public:
   smallDOUBLE():val(0){}
   smallDOUBLE(double i):val(i){}
   operator smallINT() { return val;}
};

int main()
{
    smallINT int1(10);
    smallDOUBLE DBL1(123.22);
    smallINT int2 = DBL1;
    smallDOUBLE DBL2 = int1;
}
```

Here `smallINT int2 = DBL1;` in the main works fine, but  `smallDOUBLE DBL2 = int1;` throws error saying

> return type smallDOUBLE is incomplete

during compilation.

Why does `operator smallINT() { return val;}` work

whereas  `operator smallDOUBLE() {return val;}` doesn't ?

[image]

Comment: The above code, if placed in a cpp file, does not fail to compile in main.  It does so somewhere else.  Please post code that actually demonstrates your problem and include both errors **and** the line the error occurred on.

Comment: Note that the first error is in your operator.  The error in main is irrelevant (and caused by the error in the operator).  Errors after the first are only rarely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling: in order to implement a conversion function, you need the type the function converts to to be already implemented. Just moving the definition of `operator smallDOUBLE()` after the definition of the class `smallDOUBLE` yields a compilable program.

```
class smallDOUBLE;

class smallINT
{
private:
int val;   
public:
   smallINT():val(0){}
   smallINT(int i):val(i){}
  operator smallDOUBLE();
};

class smallDOUBLE
{
private:
double val;
public:
   smallDOUBLE():val(0){}
   smallDOUBLE(double i):val(i){}
   // smallINT already defined, no problem here...
   operator smallINT() { return val;}
};

// now that smallDOUBLE is defined...
smallINT::operator smallDOUBLE(){return val;}

int main()
{
  smallINT int1(10);
  smallDOUBLE DBL1(123.22);
  smallINT int2 = DBL1;
  smallDOUBLE DBL2 = int1;
}
```

Comment: @didierc- isn't it compiler's responsibility to find the definition of the class if it is forward declared?

Comment: I think that question is complex enough to deserve to be "formally" asked, not just as a comment. If taken literally, @leemes is right. Otherwise, there are 2 possible interpretations to it: (1) could the compiler be smart enough to detect if a class is well defined after having parsed completely a translation unit. (2) couldn't the compiler assume that a declared class will be provided later (possibly by another translation unit) and have the conversion function make a call to an yet undefined symbol.

Comment: @didierc: yet... the answer is that C++ is designed to be compiled from the top to the bottom of the translation unit. The compiler does not go back and forth trying to find how to compile the code. [To some extent compiling templates may feel like that, though]

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error because the cast operator return type can't use an incomplete type. To workaround this you could declare but not define until the other class has been defined

```
class smallDOUBLE;

class smallINT
{
private:
    int val;
public:
    smallINT() :val(0){}
    smallINT(int i) :val(i){}
    operator smallDOUBLE();
};

class smallDOUBLE
{
private:
    double val;
public:
    smallDOUBLE() :val(0){}
    smallDOUBLE(double i) :val(i){}
    operator smallINT() { return val; }
};

smallINT::operator smallDOUBLE() { return val; }
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Habnxu)</kbd>